# Increase heap-space -- application space for c program on mac?

Tags: c, macos

Like written in the topic, I wonder if it is possible to increase the heap space of my c program on an OSX system,

When I run my program, at some point I get the window with the message "your system has run out of application memory".

I have written my program in c, I just compile it without any specific parameters:

```
gcc my_program.c -o my_program_exec
```

And then at some point it stops and I get the error message. My dataset is really huge, I want to generate several int matrices with about 40 000 rows and 70 000 columns

Comment: Assuming a 4-byte `int`, that's about 11.2 GB of memory. No sane OS will give you that much memory in one chunk unless e. g. you're running a huge server with a few hundred gigs of memory.

Comment: This may help... https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/setrlimit.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/setrlimit